# Looking for a OSD component

Tags: delphi

I'm looking for a Delphi OSD(on-screen display) component. I need to realize the karaoke caption effect, just like this pic:
[image: OSD]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please take a look at:

http://www.delphigeist.com/2010/09/osd-component.html

It may suit your purposes.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand you can't violate any copyright, in fact I even encourage you to use my component and even help improve it.

Comment: @dummerzeuch: The OP has edited to answer. When I wrote the comment, he just wrote "I just found this on the net" followed by a large block of code. No source or reference at all. You can't do that. Now the answer looks perfectly OK, so I have removed my downvote. [And yes, it is always a good practice to compare the edit history of the post with the timestamp of the comment.]