# karaoke (mpeg) component for delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, mpeg

I am looking for karaoke (mpeg) component for delphi  7.

**Added from duplicate**
I mean a component that can play mpeg files or do you want a special karaoke component that filters the voices from the music?

Comment: Do you mean a component that can play mpeg files or do you want a special karaoke component that filters the voices from the music?

Comment: or a timed display of the lyrics synchronized with the audio?

Comment: Did you do a websearch for Delphi and mpeg?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Ultrastar deluxe](http://ultrastardx.sourceforge.net/), an open source Singstar clone based on Pascal/Delphi.

It now uses Free Pascal for portability, but afaik used Delphi originally (and maybe still for win32 target)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to filter the vocals from a mpeg clip, then you are going to have a hard time trying to do this. The issue here is you are trying to filter out a variable frequency from the audio signal, which over time you have no idea what it is going to be. The closest thing that you *may* be able to achieve is some audio recordings deliberately record the voice track 90 degrees out of phase between the left and right channels, in which case you can 'cancel' the vocal track out by combining the audio with the same signal 90 degrees out of phase, but i beleive that MPEG compression will negate that anyways due to its spacial compression.

So no, i dont beleive this can be done, you will be better off trying to find the musical soundtrack and combining it with the video clip then playing this.

If you are simply trying to display text over a video clip (i.e. overlay) then you may want to look at:

[Looking for a OSD component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200707/looking-for-a-osd-component/5200730#5200730)

If you also need to play video files in Delphi you can use the built in media player (TMediaPlayer) or another video component (such as TVideograbber http://www.datastead.com) - the latter supports overlay/text over screen.